# Use of 'and' and 'or' in Union and intersection of sets.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

What would be the complement of...

$\{$x:x is a natural number divisible by 3 and 5$\}$

I checked it's solution and it kind of stumped me...

$\{$x:x is a positive integer which is not divisible by 3 *or* not divisible by 5$\}$

Why the word *or* has been used in the solution? Why not *and*?

Comment: [De Morgan laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) : the negation of "P **and** Q" is "not-P **or** not-Q". Thus, when you check for the *complement* of a set, you have to negate the condition defining it.

Comment: @Mauro ALLEGRANZA could you please elaborate?

Comment: If $A = \{ x \mid x \text { is blah blah} \}$, then $A^C = \{ x \mid x \text { is not blah blah } \}$.

Comment: The given set is nothing but set of all natural numbers divisible by 15. So its complement should be the set of all natural numbers not divisible by 15 which in turn implies that the natural numbers are either not divisible by 3 or not divisible by 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x$ be natural by definiton.

Let $P(x)$ be the statement "$x$ is divisible by 3".

Let $Q(x)$ be the statement "$x$ is divisible by 5".

Each statement may be either true or false, depending on $x$.

Let $A = \{x \;| \;P(x)\}$,  $B = \{x\;| \;Q(x)\}$. Such sets are called "the truth sets of $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$".

$A$ is the set of all natural numbers divisible by 3. $B$ is a set of all natural numbers divisible by 5.

By definition we have
$$
A \cup B = \{x\;| \;P(x) \lor Q(x) \},\\
A \cap B = \{x\;| \;P(x) \land Q(x) \},\\
A^{c} = \{x\;| \; \lnot P(x)\}, \\ B^{c} = \{x\;| \; \lnot Q(x)\}.
$$

The set of all natural $x$ divisible by 3 and 5 is $A \cap B$. Its complement is $(A \cap B)^{c}=A^c \cup B^c$.

It follows that
$$
A^c \cup B^c = \{x\;| \; \lnot P(x) \lor \lnot Q(x) \}.
$$

Note that the symbols "$\cap$" and "$\land$" look similar, and so do the symbols "$\cup$" and "$\lor$".

**P.S.** For further understanding of logic and set theory (and their interconnection) I would recommend you to read the book "How to Prove It" by Daniel J. Velleman.

Comment: You have answered beautifully.

Answer (score 2):

An element $x\in\mathbb N_+$ is in the complement of the set you mention if and only if it is not true that $x$ satisfies **both** the conditions that are mentioned. So $x$ will not satisfy the first **or** $x$ will not satisfy the second. It is possible that in that case $x$ will not satisfy both (that is not excluded by "or") but that is not necessary.